# How do you create an AWS S3 bucket with versioning enabled from the cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

How do you create a private S3 bucket with versioning enabled?

I can't quite figure it out from https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/mb.html nor https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/create-bucket.html

There is scant documentation from the cli too:

```
$ aws s3 mb help
$ aws --version
aws-cli/2.7.25 Python/3.9.11 Linux/5.18.16-arch1-1 exe/x86_64.arch prompt/off
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no parameter to request the bucket to be created with Versioning enabled.

However, if ObjectLock is specified, then this forces Versioning to also be enabled:

```
aws s3api create-bucket --bucket MY-BUCKET --object-lock-enabled-for-bucket --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=ap-southeast-2
```

However the S3 management console then says:

> Once Amazon S3 Object Lock is enabled, you can't disable Object Lock or suspend Bucket Versioning for the bucket.

The alternative is to create the bucket and *THEN* enable Versioning.

Comment: Is the location constraint needed?

Comment: The `LocationConstraint` tells S3 in which Region the bucket should be created (which is not necessarily the region that you have connected to). It didn't let me create the bucket unless I provided the `LocationConstraint`, but you are welcome to experiment!

Comment: I find when I use that command, as opposed to aws s3 mb, i get permission denied. Maybe it's a better approach to mb, and add versioning later.